# ConcurrentHashMap in @Singleton with ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, concurrenthashmap

I have a @Singleton with ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN. In this Singleton, I have a MemcachedClient (net.rubyeye.xmemcached), which connects to the memcached server - so far so well.
Since I have some big objects, where the transmition/deserialization is too slow (50ms or more), I decided to implement a L2-Cache with the idea to also store some specific key-value pairs in a local hashmap (-> ConcurrentHashMap) and first try to read it from there (and yes, I have a scaled environment, i.e. multiple applications sharing the same mamcached - that is why I use memcached: if a object is invalidated, all nodes are notifed to invalidate their local L2 key-value pair and refetch it from mecached).

What I observe now on productive system is that there are strange behviours which may seem to come from wrong data read from my L2 cache. If I disable it, all is OK again; on the other hand, if I debug and test it with L2 cache locally (same infrastructure as productive system but almost no load), it OK as well.

So I wonder if I have any concurrency issue even though I use `ConcurrentHashMap`. In fact, I do not have any exception; but it looks like it fetches wrong key-value pairs or the fetched data is altered in any way. I have not yet found out, what exactly goes wrong; I just remarked that if I fetch an object (which is a list of objects) from my ConcurrentHashMap and do .stream().filter(...) on it, I get wrong entries at the end, which are not matching the filter. This behaviour does only appear, if I fetch from my "L2 cache"; if I fetch from memcached, all is always OK.

My Service looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class CacheService
{
    private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;


    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, L2Entry> l2Cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ...
}
```

Is this per se a problem, using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in a `@Singleton` with `ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN`?

What is going on, if I read from the hash map? Do I get a copy of the data? So any modifs on the hash map will not alter the data?

static/non static: The `l2Cache` hash map member is not declared as `static` since my singleton should be anyway a single instance... is this wrong?

Any idea, what could give me wrong data from my hash map would be helpful...

Comment: Perhaps there is a latency issue under load where it's taking too long to invalidate the local L2 object?  Can you reproduce the issue locally under load?  Does it have to be such a "big" object?  Can it be broken up?

Comment: @Andrew S: Currently, I can not reproduce it, even not under load. Since the data is almost constant (I think that is one of the *must be* to use such a two level caching - and this even over multiple noded), I could not imagine an issue caused by invalidation.